# Feature/characteristic causing dislike

Tags: single-word-requests

While working on a new blog post, I wanted to say that there was one thing in particular I didn't like about a song I'm reviewing.  I started off with:

> My only ___ with this song is that ...

I'm trying to think of what word I can use here, to describe a problem I have with how the song is put together.  I could try:

> My only problem with this song is that ...

But I want to say something more specific, it's less than a problem but more than just something that bothers me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we approach 500 years since Luther's 95 theses, may I suggest **grievance**?

> • a real or imagined wrong or other cause for complaint or protest, especially unfair treatment: failure to redress genuine grievances.
>
> • an official statement of a complaint over something believed to be wrong or unfair: three pilots have filed grievances against the company.
>
> • a feeling of resentment over something believed to be wrong or unfair: he was nursing a grievance.

Comment: Perfect, just pretentious enough to belong on my blog!

Answer (score 1):

You can use ***grouch*** to mean a *trivial complaint*.

> My only ***grouch*** with this song is that ...

ODO:

> **[grouch](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grouch)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1.1**
>   *A trivial complaint*:
>   ‘my only real grouch was that the children's chorus was less easy on the ear’

Also perhaps, a ***grouse*** (or synonym ***grumble***) which is a complaint (not necessarily *trivial*).
Also, a ***niggle***.

ODO:

> ***[grouse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/grouse)***
>   *NOUN*
>
> *A **complaint** or **grumble***:
>   ‘our biggest grouse was about the noise of construction work’
>
> **[niggle](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/niggle)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> A trivial criticism, discomfort, or annoyance:
>   ‘it is an excellent
>   book except for my few niggles’